# openrefine extracting values between symbols

Tags: regex, openrefine, grel

I am trying to extract string of text from a whole field with Openrefine.
This is an extract of my dataset:

```
172.    D3B: 23Y1-Up, 27Y1-Up  (36 LK) 6-S/F Rollers, 4-D/F Rollers, 2-Carrier Rollers
179.    D3C: 23Y2508-UP (37LK) 6-S/F, 4-D/F, 2-T/C  
180.    27Y5050-UP (37LK) 6-S/F, 4-D/F, 2-T/C   
181.    2XF622-UP (37LK) 6-S/F, 4-D/F, 2-T/C    
182.    3RF0147-UP (36LK) 6-S/F, 4-D/F, 2-T/C
200.    D4D:67A1-UP, 78A1-UP, 85A1-UP, 86A1-UP, 59J1-644, 58J1-UP, 49J1-473, 22C1-UP, 91A1-UP, 88A1-UP
```

I want to extract `23Y1-Up, 27Y1-Up`  from record 172,
`23Y2508-UP` from record 179, `27Y5050-UP` from record 180 and the whole `67A1-UP, 78A1-UP, 85A1-UP, 86A1-UP, 59J1-644, 58J1-UP, 49J1-473, 22C1-UP, 91A1-UP, 88A1-UP` from record 200

So basically the rule would be to extract everything between `:`if present and `(` if present. Maybe restricting it to where there is one or more occurrence of the string `UP`

So I am adding a new column based on existing column using value.match.
I tried to adapt some query to my scope but I am very far from succeding despite multiple attempts.
I started with this regex expression  `value.match(/\:?\s*(\w+\.?)+?.*/)[0]` that I tought would isolate any word AFTER the semicolon (and the space) but it works only with words BEFORE...
Yesterday I successfully extracted the numbers before the LK that is also relevant information for my dataset, but I can't grasp this.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using [match](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions/#matchs-p) matches the whole string.

You can use a single capture group with a negated character class to exclude matching `(`

```
^[^:]*:\s*([^(]+).*$
```

- `^[^:]*:\s*` Match until the first `:` followed by optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^(]+` Match 1+ occurrence of any char except `(`
- `)` Close group 1
- `.*$` Match the rest of the line

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oTOOwa/1)

Or capture in a group matching only word characters separated by a hyphen

```
^[^:]*:\s*(\w+-\w+(?:,\s+\w+-\w+)*).*$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDdxfG/1)

Comment: Hi Thanks. This works great in regex, but not in openrefine's GREL using value.match. I am trying to figure out how to adapt it based on this document https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions/#string-functions

Comment: @datacleaner Try matching the entire string `^[^:]*:\s*([^(]+).*$` https://regex101.com/r/cRwYf8/1 llike `"179.    D3C: 23Y2508-UP (37LK) 6-S/F, 4-D/F, 2-T/C".match(/^[^:]*:\s*([^(]+).*$/)`

Comment: Kind of works.. still missing values from lines that do not have the semicolon which is optional. Also i have this line with semicolon that is showing null... 977E: 20A2509-4222    (40 Link) 6-S/F , 8-D/F , 4-

Comment: @datacleaner Can you give an example of a line without a `:` with the expected match? You can update the link with the example and add it again to a comment https://regex101.com/r/cRwYf8/1

Comment: line 180 of my post should match for 27Y5050-UP

Comment: @datacleaner This would match it https://regex101.com/r/DQeMQy/1 `^\d+\.\s*(?:\w+:)?\s*([^(]+).*$`  or this https://regex101.com/r/WccLJx/1 `^\d+\.\s*(?:\w+:)?\s*(\w+-\w+(?:,\s+\w+-\w+)*).*$`

Comment: Thanks, this works great in the editor, unfortunately not in GREL..... can't understand why. I used value.match and the opening/closing slash like this `value.match(/^\d+\.\s*(?:\w+:)?\s*(\w+-\w+(?:,\s+\w+-\w+)*).*$/)`

Comment: @datacleaner Ther are no leading whitespaces in the line? So the example data has a digit directly at the start of the line? Try it like this without the anchors and leading whitespace https://regex101.com/r/c5hjty/1 `\s*\d+\.\s*(?:\w+:)?\s*(\w+-\w+(?:,\s+\w+-\w+)*).*`

Comment: All these results in null. I think it is because of how value.match works as explained here...https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions/#string-functions under "match (p,s).Your regex code is correct. I only managed to get some values ouf of this `value.match(/A*(\w+-\w+(?:,\s+\w+-\w+)*).*/)` still better than nothing...thx

Comment: @datacleaner I don't see an `A` but you can also skip the digits part and try a non greedy dot `.*?(?:\w+:)?\s*(\w+-\w+(?:,\s+\w+-\w+)*).*`